# Inverse of keras.Flatten for building autoencoder

Tags: python, keras, autoencoder

My goal is to build a convolutional autoencoder that encodes input image to flat vector of size `(10,1)`. I followed the example from keras [documentation](https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html) and modified it for my purposes. Unfortunetely, the model like this:

```
input_img = Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))

x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Flatten()(x)

encoded = Dense(units = 10, activation = 'relu')(x)


x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoded)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
decoded = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)

autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoded)
```

gives me

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv2d_39: expected ndim=4, found ndim=2
```

I think I should add some layer to my Decoder to inverse the effect of Flatten, but wasn't really sure which one. Can you help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you want to have specifically (10,1) shape for the vector?
You are trying to then do convolutions on that with kernel of size 3x3, which does not really make sense.

The shape a convolutional layer takes in has height, width and channels. The output of the dense layer has to be reshaped which can be done with Reshape layer.
You can then reshape it to for example 5x2 with single channel.

```
encoded = Reshape((5, 2, 1))(encoded)
```

Comment: Not married to 10. Just a smaller number of parameters after encoding in 1D vector. So if last maxpooling of encoder gives me shape `(None, 7, 7, 8)` it means that after Flatten I'd have 7*7*8 = 392 output shape, right? So say that I connect it to my 10 units. Then I should add another Dense layer (the first one in decoder, go get my 392 output back, and reshape it to (7, 7, 8)?